# Integrating the function $\alpha^{2}\sin^{2}\left( \dfrac {2 \pi x}{w}\right)$

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I need to find

$\int ^{x}_{0} \alpha^{2}\sin^{2}\left( \dfrac {2 \pi x}{w}\right) dL$

where

$L=\dfrac {2kE\left( \dfrac {2\pi \alpha }{k}\right) }{\pi}\approx \dfrac {k+w}{2}\left( \dfrac {3\left( k-w\right)^{2}}{\left( k+w\right) \left( 10k+10w+\sqrt {k^{2}+w^{2}+14kw}\right) }+1\right)$

$k=\sqrt {4\pi ^{2}\alpha ^{2}+w^{2}}$

and

$E\left( m\right)=\int^{\dfrac {\pi}{2}}_{0}\sqrt {1-m^{2}\sin ^{2}\theta }d\theta$.

I have tried approximating $L$ and solving for $\alpha$ and $w$ in order to substitue into the first equation but it seems for the approximation to maintain a reasonable level of accuracy, the solutions for $\alpha$ and $w$ must be horrendously long.

I would greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the whole setup here. What is constant, and what is a function of what? Also, you are integrating with respect to $L$, but $L$ is not an independent variable, it is a function of $\alpha$, which is also in the integrand. Can you be a bit more explicit?

Comment: Im sorry but there is no way that's the question given to you, and if it is let the computer crunch your result, L is both a function of $\omega$ and $\alpha$ which are both in the integrand in various powers...

Comment: @Ian $L=f(\alpha,w)$. $x$, $w$ and $\alpha$ are variables, please tell if I need to be/how to be more explicit.

Comment: @Avrham Aton this question hasn't been directly assigned to me and the problem is (as said in the question), $\alpha$ and $w$ are both horrendously long and therefore hard to work with, especially since I am unable to work with any mathematical programs that would crunch my results.

Comment: @J.D'Almbert OK, so $L$ depends on $\alpha$ and $w$. If it only depended on one of them, integrating with respect to $L$ would be OK, provided $L$ is an injective function (which it is, at least on $[0,1]$). But since $L$ is a function of two variables, it is ambiguous to integrate with respect to $L$. (I suspect you wish to integrate $\alpha^2 \sin \left ( \frac{2 \pi x}{w} \right )$ over $\{ (\alpha,w) : 0 \leq L(\alpha,w) \leq x \}$, but that doesn't tell me what measure you want to use on that set.) Further disambiguation is required to be able to help you.

Comment: @Ian I understand your point but I don't understand why it is ambiguous. For instance since $\alpha=f(w,L)$ and $w=g(\alpha,L)$ wouldn't I be able to integrate the first equation if I could ascertain $\alpha$ and $w$ in terms of their respective functions?

Comment: @Ian I am not familiar with a "measure" of a set, could you elaborate?

Comment: There's still ambiguity here unless you can prove that $L(\alpha,w)$ is injective. Generically speaking it will not be; in particular it would not be if $L$ were linear. If $L$ is not injective, then you have to describe how the multiple solutions should be weighted in the integral, which becomes a huge mess involving the topology of level sets.

Comment: Here's one way of thinking about it. Consider just interpolating $E$ linearly, that is, consider $F(m)=1-m$. Even in this simple case, you wind up with $G(\alpha,w)=\frac{2 \sqrt{4 \pi^2 \alpha^2 + w^2} \left ( 1 - \frac{2 \pi \alpha}{\sqrt{4 \pi^2 \alpha^2 + w^2} \right )}{\pi}$. This is probably not injective, in that it is a rational function of $\alpha$ and $w$ separately.

Comment: $G(\alpha,w)=\frac{2 \sqrt{4 \pi^2 \alpha^2 + w^2} \left ( 1 - \frac{2 \pi \alpha}{\sqrt{4 \pi^2 \alpha^2 + w^2}} \right )}{\pi}$ was intended (I missed a close bracket).